# Rigorous stability analysis of infinite dimensional ODEs : How to bound the tails?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems, mp.mathematical-physics

---

My question is about linear stability analysis of dynamical systems obtained by discretizing linear(ized) partial differential equations. Consider,
$\dot{x}=Ax$, where $x$ is the infinite dimensional vector of coefficients, and $A$ a linear operator in an countably finite basis of a nice function space (using, say Fourier series on a circle, or Hermite on $\mathbb{R}$). **Assume** that the PDE system is of the type that  the full spectrum of $A$ determines the stability.

Usually, physics/engineering papers impose an arbitrary cut-off on number of modes considered, and give analytical/numerical results on the spectrum of this truncation of $A$ to prove/disprove stability.

My question is: How does one make such arguments rigorous ? Are there some standard tricks that can enable one to take into account the neglected modes in a rigorous manner ?

Specifically, I am looking for examples/papers where stability was deduced based on considering the operator acting on a subset of modes, and estimating the effect of "tails" (or neglected modes).

Comment: What you say is clear is not clear at all. Indeed, it is in general false. Stability of infinite dimensional systems is in general not determined by the spectrum. Even when it is, finite dimensional approximation of the spectrum is a topic for entire books.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I have edited to restrict to only those systems where spectrum does determine stability. Note that I am not asking for computation of the full spectrum, but rather concluding stability using a combination of analysis of the truncated system and some estimate of the neglected modes.